Plating a type with generic-lens
Is there a way to write Plated instances using generic-lens? optics has gplate - is there something similar for the lens universe?
data Expr = Lit Int | Add Expr Expr deriving Generic
instance Plated Expr where
    plate = -- what goes here?

I tried types but that appears to behave as id when s and a match (like biplate does).

gplate?

Thanks! Reading comprehension failure on my part. (In my defense it's all the way at the bottom of the page!) If you wanna write that as an answer I'll accept.
